# Signing C# Assembly in IDE vs with signtool.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-signing

I suspect I already know the answer to this question but I'll ask it anyway.  A third party vendor suggested I sign my C# EXE using the VS2010 signing property tab.  However, my build process currently obfuscates my EXE and then signs it with signtool.exe  and a Comodo certificate.

Am I correct in saying that I'm already doing whatever it is that the project signing tab in VS already offers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, my build process currently obfuscates my EXE and then signs it with signtool.exe and a **Comodo certificate**

I'll assume you are referring to *Code Signing* rather than Strong Naming.

> Am I correct in saying that I'm already doing whatever it is that the project signing tab in VS already offers?

If you are referring to the *manifest signing* in the **Signing** tab then *yes*.

Both result in *manifest signing* (Code Signing) and in the case of obfuscation, has to be performed after the obfuscation step (because the latter removes the signing).

### Tell me more

- Brower, J, *"Code Signing in Visual Studio"*, https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/code-signing-visual-studio-jason-brower, retrieved 2016/11/22
- Microsoft, *"Signing Page, Project Designer"*, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k50fs3b.aspx, retrieved 2016/11/22

Comment: Thanks, that explains it nicely.  I'm talking about an EXE file so as far as I am aware strong naming is of no real use.